# Нужна помощь в применении методов в массиве

Tags: java

Сделал массив. Сделал методы по списку заданий(вывести массив в консоль, заменить местами макс. и мин. элемент и вывести в консоль, найти сумму четных элементов и вывести в консоль, заменить нулями отриц. элем и вывести в консоль, найти разницу среднего и мин. элемента и вывести в консоль и вывести все элементы, которые встречаются больше одного раза вместе с количеством вхождений). Все методы вроде работают но как это все собрать воедино я не понимаю и прошу помочь исправить синтаксис и собрать программу "воедино")

```
import java.util.Arrays;

  public class Massiv {
      private final int[] mas;

    public Massiv(int size) {
            this.mas = new int[size];
           
            int maxNegIndex = 0;        
            int minPosIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {

                mas[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 21) - 10);
                System.out.println("Вывод массива" + mas);
                return mas;//? Как написать что бы выводилось корректно?                       
            }
            public int replacementOfElements() {  //? Как оформить замену элементов для корректного вывода в консоль?
                            
            if (mas[i] < 0) { //У [i] нет связи с массивом, как сделать?
                if (mas[i] > mas[maxNegIndex]) maxNegIndex = i;
                if (mas[maxNegIndex] >= 0) maxNegIndex = i;
            } else if (mas[i] > 0) {
                if (mas[i] < mas[minPosIndex]) minPosIndex = i;
                if (mas[minPosIndex] <= 0) minPosIndex = i;
            
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
        int temp = mas[maxNegIndex];
        mas[maxNegIndex] = mas[minPosIndex];
        mas[minPosIndex] = temp;
       return mas; // Какая то синтаксическая ошибка(
        }
     public int sumEvenElements() {        
            return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i->i % 2 == 0).sum();
        }

        public int[] evenElements() {
            return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i->i % 2 == 0).toArray();
        }
        
     //замена на 0 отриц. элем.
        public int zeroReplacementElements () {
           int[] mas = new int [i]
        
                 if (mas[i] < 0) {
                    mas[i] = 0;
                    }
                // System.out.println("замена на 0 отрицательных чисел" + zeroReplacementElements ());  
    }
      //  В массиве целых чисел найти разницу между средним арифметическим и значением минимального элемента.
        public int[] arithmeticDifference() {//как присоеденить массив к [i] что бы работал цикл
            
         int sumMas = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
          sumMas = sumMas + mas[i];
            }
          int avg = sumMas / mas[SIZE];//как заставить работать?

          int minMas = mas[MAX];// как заставить работать?
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                if (mas[i] < mas[MAX] {
                    minMas = mas[i];*/
                } 
                public int[] arithmeticDifference() {// как это собрать в единый метод вычисления разницы?
                    
          int result_Task4 = avg - minMas; 
                    return ;
          //System.out.println("Разница между средним арифметическим и минимальным элемнентом:" + result_Task4);
         
        //В массиве элементов вывести значения которые встречаются больше одного раза вместе с количеством вхождений
         public int[] arrayOfIntegers() {
                    
        int[][] mas = new int[SIZE + 1][2];// как это собрать в единый метод и как к нему обратить в мейне?
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          arr[i][0] = i - 10;
          } 

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                 if (arr[i][0] == mas[j])
          arr[i][1]++;
          }
     } 

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i][1] > 1)
                    return;
          //System.out.println("Число " + arr[i][0] + " встречается " + arr[i][1] + " раз");
          } 
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                 Massiv massiv = new Massiv(20);
                 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv.generate()));

                 int[] evenElements = massiv.evenElements();
                 System.out.println("Четные элементы: " + Arrays.toString(evenElements));
                 System.out.println("Всего четных элементов: " + evenElements.length);
                 System.out.println("Их сумма равна: " + massiv.sumEvenElements());
                 System.out.println("Замена четных чисел на ноль" + );
                System.out.println("Подсчет разницы между средним и минимальным значением" + );
                System.out.println("В массиве элементов вывести значения которые встречаются больше одного раза вместе с количеством вхождений." +);
             }

         }
```

---

Моя попытка исправить. Но ничего не выводиться в консоль и на 1 и 3 методе компилятор ругается(при выводе именно). А так ошибок нет?!

В чем тут дело? Как всё таки сделать это задание рабочим?!

```
public class Task1 {
    
    public final int[] array;

    public Task1(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
    
    // 1. поменять местами максимальный отрицательный элемент и минимальный положительный.
    public int[] option1() {
        int iMaxNeg = 0;
        int iMinPos = 0;
        
        /* вычисление индексов макс. отриц. и мин. полож. элементов */
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < 0 && array[i] > array[iMaxNeg]) iMaxNeg = i;
            if (array[i] > 0 && array[i] < array[iMinPos]) iMinPos = i;
        }
        
        /* свап элементов */
        int tmp = array[iMaxNeg];
        array[iMaxNeg] = array[iMinPos];
        array[iMinPos] = tmp;
        return array;
    }

    // 2. определить сумму элементов, состоящих на чётных позициях.
    public int option2() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) sum += array[i];
        return sum;
    }

    // 3. заменить нулями отрицательные элементы.
    public int[] option3() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < 0) array[i] = 0;
        }
        return array;
    }

    // 4. найти разницу между средним арифметическим и значение минимального элемента.
    public double option4() {
        double average = 0; // среднее арифметическое
        int minElement = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // минимальное значение 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            average += array[i];
            if (array[i] < minElement) minElement = array[i];
        }
        return average / array.length - minElement;
    }
    
    // 5. вывести все элементы, которые встречаются больше одного раза и индексы которых нечётные.
    public int[] option5() {
        int[] countMeets = new int[21];
        int length = 0; // длина результирующего массива
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            countMeets[array[i] + 10]++;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
            if (countMeets[array[i] + 10] > 1) {
                length++;
            }
        }
        int[] result = new int[length]; // возвращаемый массив
        int j = 0; // индекс массива result
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
            if (countMeets[array[i] + 10] > 1) {
                result[j++] = array[i]; // инкрементируем j после присвоения значения j-тому элементу
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // пересоздание массива
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int [] arr = new int[20];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 21) - 10);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        
        Task1 task = new Task1(arr);
        
        System.out.println("*************************************************");        
        System.out.println("Replacement max. and min elements in places" + java.util.Arrays.toString(task.option1()));
        System.out.println("Their sum is equal to : " + task.option2());
        System.out.println("Replacing negative numbers with zero : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(task.option1()));
        System.out.println("Calculating the difference between the average and minimum value : " + task.option4());
        System.out.println("In the array of elements, display values that occur more than once together with the number of occurrences: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(task.option1()));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, откуда у вас взялась уверенность, что этот код должен работать, учитывая в каком он состоянии, но попытка хорошая))
попробуйте так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Massiv {

    private final int[] mas;

    public Massiv(int [] mas) {
        this.mas = mas;
    }

    //вывод массива в консоль
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(mas);
    }

    public Massiv replaceMinMaxElement() {

        int min=0,max=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {            
            if (mas[i]<mas[min]) min = i;
            if (mas[i]>mas[max]) max = i;
        }

        int tmp = mas[min];
        mas[min] = mas[max];
        mas[max] = tmp;
        return this;
    }

    //сумма четных элементов
    public int sumEvenElements() {
        return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).sum();
    }

    //выбор четных элементов
    public int[] evenElements() {
        return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).toArray();
    }

    //замена на 0 отриц. элем.
    public Massiv zeroReplacementElements() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            if (mas[i] < 0) mas[i] = 0;
        }
        return this;
    }

    //В массиве целых чисел найти разницу между средним арифметическим и значением минимального элемента.
    public double arithmeticDifference() {        
        double average = Arrays.stream(mas).average().getAsDouble();
        int min = Arrays.stream(mas).min().getAsInt();
        return average - min;
    }

    //В массиве элементов вывести значения которые встречаются больше одного раза вместе с количеством вхождений
    public Map<Integer, Long> arrayOfIntegers() {
        return Arrays.stream(mas).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arraySize = 10;        
        int [] mas = new int[arraySize];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            mas[i] = r.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println(mas[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("*************************************************");

        Massiv massiv = new Massiv(mas);


        int[] evenElements = massiv.evenElements();

        System.out.println("Четные элементы : " + Arrays.toString(evenElements));
        System.out.println("Всего четных элементов : " + evenElements.length);
        System.out.println("Их сумма равна : " + massiv.sumEvenElements());

        System.out.print("Замена отрицательных чисел на ноль : " + massiv.replaceMinMaxElement());

        System.out.println("Подсчет разницы между средним и минимальным значением : " + massiv.arithmeticDifference());
        System.out.println("В массиве элементов вывести значения которые встречаются больше одного раза вместе с количеством вхождений : " + massiv.arrayOfIntegers());
    }

}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо) Подредактировал "под задание"))) Но спасибо что помогли собрать всё воедино) Только вопрос... для чего используется переменная  @Override? (немного пояснений если не сложно, плиз)

Comment: @ Никита Кузьмищев эта аннотация говорит о том, что данный метод переопределен. она необязательная. если е убрать поведение не изменится. все дело в том, что все классы в джавен по умолчанию наследуются от класса Object.так вот, метод toString() - метод именно этого класса. я же в классе-наследнике изменяю поведения базового метода суперкласса - переопределяю его. примерно так

Comment: Спасибо за ответы)

Comment: А если стримы, коллекции и т.д использоваться запрещено, то как бы сделать эту задачу?

Comment: @ Никита Кузьмищев я бы для начала выяснил что такое и.т.д.)) просто "итд" предполагает какой-то логический ряд, а в данном случае это звучит примерно так: я вчера видел соседа, самолет и.т.д. может одуванчик? одуванчик подходит, как по мне))) условия нужны более точные))

Comment: оказалось что в задании нельзя"в этом задании нельзя использовать Arrays, тем более стримы. пожалуйста, сделай через циклы."((( что капец как удлиняет код особенно в последнем задании, где придется делать массив в массиве для счетчика(((

Comment: @ Дмитрий попробовал исправить задание, глянете,пожалуйста, что не так с моим ответом?

Comment: @ Никита Кузьмищев я отредактировал ваш код в вашем вопросе. теперь это компилируется и выполняется. подправил кое-что в методах (править все по второму кругу не вижу смысла, т.к. я уже написал вам рабочее решение), но это не гарантирует корректность работы методов. Вы решили генерировать рандомный массив - это не самое хорошее решение. в идеале нужно воспользоваться junit и написать юнит-тесты для каждого метода.

Comment: @ Дмитрий спасибо за помощь) Наверное это будет следующий этап)